How to push data to the dynamo db table using aws glue, api gateway and lambda from aws s3
#This is my glue spark code
import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job
import requests
import json
## @params: [JOB_NAME]
args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ['JOB_NAME'])

sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args['JOB_NAME'], args)

s3_input = "s3://dynamodb-bucket-******/raw/"
dynamic_frame = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_options(connection_type="s3",connection_options={"paths":     [s3_input]},format="csv",format_options={"withHeader":True})
df=dynamic_frame.toDF()
json_data=df.toJSON().collect()

api_url="https://*****.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev"
for record in json_data:
    headers={'Content-Type':'application/json'}
    response=requests.post(api_url,data=record,headers=headers)
    if response.status_code!=200:
        print("Error sending data:{response.content}")

job.commit()

#This is my lambda function
import json
import boto3

dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
table=dynamodb.Table('my_dynamodb_table')
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    data=json.loads(event['data']['headers'])
    table.put_item(Item=data)
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('Data inserted successfully')
    }

#This is the error I'm getting in my lambda function. Canyou please help?
\[ERROR\] KeyError: 'data'
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 8, in lambda_handler
data=json.loads(event\['data'\]\['headers'\])

I have created a glue job to pick csv file from s3 and transform it to json and created api gateway endpoint using api gateway anda lambda function. How to push data to the dynamo db table using api gateway and lambda
